# Are there any independently verifiable auth token mechanisms?

Tags: authentication, permissions, token

I'm looking at building a set of services that require an auth system but ideally I'd want them to be able validate these tokens without hitting a central auth service to check for every request.

Are there any known ways of doing this, better than something like a signed expiry-stamped permission enumeration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JWT](http://jwt.io/) should suit you well, but it is actually a singed (or also encrypted if you need), expire-stamped list of data.

Keep in mind that there is no way to revoke (logout) such stateless tokens, what, depending on situation, might be a non-issue or a complicated problem to solve.